# Processing video not working

Tags: video, processing

I am using Processing 2.2.1.

I followed these steps: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Video_Issues

and my video still doesn't work. There is no error, but the image is black.

I've installed QuickTime 7.7.5 and WinVDIG 1.0.1. When I run QTCap the image is also black, but when I open video settings I see myself...

In processing this is the code to test if the video is working:

```
import processing.video.*;


Capture video;


void setup() {
  size(320,240);
   String[] cameras = Capture.list();

   if (cameras.length == 0) {
    println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
    exit();
  } else {
    println("Available cameras:");
    for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
      println(cameras[i]);
    }
  }

  video = new Capture(this,320,240,30);
}

void draw() {

  if (video.available()) {
    println("video");
    video.read();
  }
  else{
  println("no video");
  }
 image(video,0,0);
}
```

The console shows to me:

```
Available cameras:
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=640x480,fps=5
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=640x480,fps=30
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=352x288,fps=5
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=352x288,fps=30
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=320x240,fps=5
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=320x240,fps=30
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=176x144,fps=5
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=176x144,fps=30
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=160x120,fps=5
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=160x120,fps=30
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=1280x960,fps=5
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=1280x960,fps=15/2
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=1280x1024,fps=5
    name=Lenovo EasyCamera,size=1280x1024,fps=15/2
    no video
    no video
    no video
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this line:

```
video = new Capture(this,320,240,30);
```

You are required to `start();` the capture by adding:

```
video.start();
```

Without this the capture doesn't start and you see a black screen.

See the [documentation](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Capture.html) here.